# Why does the next tag badge need a colon, but a regular badge doesn't?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, grammar

In the user profile page you can see progress for the next badges. One for regular (right block) and one for tag badge (left block):

> [image]

Why does a sentence in one case end with a colon, but in another it doesn't?

I think they should be put in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon has been removed from the "Next tag badge" sentence:

> [image]